Can I define different pytest configurations?
I've just started working in a git repo that has three separate, but related, python root folders, each with their own set of tests. I'm setting up pytest as the test framework as per the instructions at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_test-configuration-settings
I have defined "python.testing.cwd":"path/to/python/root" in settings.json but because there are three root folders I have to keep changing that value depending on which set of tests I want to run.
Is there perhaps a means by which I can define different test configurations (essentially define those three different roots) and easily switch between them without having to open up settings.json?
